# set_weights stopped working on tensorflow 2

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Updating our code base from keras --> tensorflow.keras for unrelated reasons.

keras 2.3.1
tensorflow 2.1.0

This code works on keras, but fails on tf.keras:

```
weights = applications.VGG16(weights='imagenet', include_top=False).get_weights()
model.set_weights(tempweights)
```

Error:

```
You called `set_weights(weights)` on layer "model" with a  weight list of length 26, but the layer was expecting 32 weights. Provided weights: [array([[[[ 4.29470569e-01,  1.17273867e-01,  3.40...
```

using keras.applications.VGG16().get_weights() does not fix it, results in exact same error.

Have examined these github issues that look similar, but wasn't able to find the cause of my issue:

https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/7229
https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4753

The following works:

```
model.weights[0] = weights[0]
```

It SEEMS Like keras.model.set_weights() had some behavior for dealing with mismatched weights, but tf.tensorflow.keras does not have this behavior?

Confirmed. Behavior has changed. Include_top=True fixed it in our specific case, because that made our models match up. Keras doesn't throw errors when models don't match, and I'm not sure exactly *what* it does in that case. Not going to investigate that though. Leaving the solution here.

Comment: Where did you get `tempweights` from?

Comment: typo, it should just say 'weights'.